# hard coded links and .env PORT

Tags: heroku, loopbackjs, create-react-app, cloud9

[5 video tutorial series](https://youtu.be/Mx-cywTNy8s)
[Original LoopBack & React tutorial from Traversy for comparison](https://github.com/bradtraversy/meetupz)

I've followed the tutorial and got it to function on Cloud 9 in developement.. 
I wasn't sure about how to set the port to an Environment variable, so I hardcoded my ports with 8080 for Cloud 9.. now I'm trying to run it on Heroku and all my axios posts are broken.

I think I changed all the links back from

```
axios.get(`http://foood-liberation-front-turtlewolfe.c9users.io:8080/api/Barrels/${barrelID}`)
```

to `` axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/Barrels/${barrelID}`) ``
but I'm still missing something, I can get it to compile on Heroku at

https://food-liberation-frontz.herokuapp.com

but when I click on the save link to add a new barrel, it's broken.

```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class AddBarrel extends Component {

    addBarrel(newBarrel){
        console.log(newBarrel);
        axios.request({
            method:'post',
            url:'http://foood-liberation-front-turtlewolfe.c9users.io:8080/api/Barrels',
            data: newBarrel
        }).then(response => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }).catch( err => console.log(err));
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        const newBarrel = {
            Name: this.refs.Name.value,
            barrel_number: this.refs.barrel_number.value,
            contents: this.refs.contents.value,
            date_last_checked: this.refs.date_last_checked.value,
            date_planted: this.refs.date_planted.value,
            location: this.refs.location.value,
            size: this.refs.size.value,
            notes: this.refs.notes.value
        }
        this.addBarrel(newBarrel);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render () {
    return (
            <div className = "container green lighten-3" >
            <br />
            <Link className = "btn grey" to = "/">back</Link>
            <h6>add a Barrel</h6>
            <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "Name" ref = "Name" />
                    <label htmlFor = "Name" >Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "barrel_number" ref = "barrel_number" />
                    <label htmlFor = "barrel_number" >barrel number</label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "contents" ref = "contents" />
                    <label htmlFor = "contents" >contents</label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "date" name = "date_planted" ref = "date_planted" />
                    <label htmlFor = "date_planted" ></label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "date" name = "date_last_checked" ref = "date_last_checked" />
                    <label htmlFor = "date_last_checked" ></label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "location" ref = "location" />
                    <label htmlFor = "location" >location</label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "size" ref = "size" />
                    <label htmlFor = "size" >size</label>
                </div>
                <div className = "input-field" >
                    <input type = "text" name = "notes" ref = "notes" />
                    <label htmlFor = "notes" >notes</label>
                </div>                

                <input type = "submit" value = "Save" className = "btn" />
            </form>
            </div>
           )
}
}

export default AddBarrel;
```

```

Comment: https://github.com/TurtleWolf/Food_Liberation_Front8080  I made a new repository, this one should all be localhost:8080 I'd previously forgot to change the server configuration. Next, I'm installing a local version of Node. I've liked developing online, but it may be easier to debug a local build where I can leave it at :3000, I only changed it to :8080 to run online at C9

Comment: I made this version with localhost:3000, I'm hoping to try it in a local environment this evening. https://github.com/TurtleWolf/Food_Liberation_Front3000

Comment: This feels relevant, it is the first project I've tried the react router on and it's pretty much the second subject under deployment.. 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Comment: after searching the repo for 'get' I think I need to refactor in [server/server.js](https://github.com/TurtleWolf/Food_Liberation_Front8080/blob/b703806c33eff6aa9c36d88c038f25226df87870/server/server.js)

Comment: It looks like they are adding a wild card to account for React Router, but the example is for Express, not LoopBack, so I'm not sure how I should refactor this part. 

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7327259/38036381-94f0f9ea-3274-11e8-9395-1bcd39643bce.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined what your application should do when the server receives the `POST` request you've defined above from the front end? For example...

In your React component above your `POST` request might look like this. I've modified your code above, specifically the URL. Note that your browser is already pointed to your application's URL, but you're looking to make a `POST` request to a *specific* route *within* your application.

```
axios.request({
  method:'post',
  url:'/api/Barrels',
  data: newBarrel
})
```

Your server would receive the request to that route, do some stuff, and respond accordingly. The code below would probably live in `server.js`.

```
app.post('/api/Barrels', function (req, res) {
  res.send('STUFF BACK TO FRONT END')
})
```

Comment: yes.. I think I get this it may be late tonight before I can try it.. but yes, I understand what you're saying. I think my original question is misleading.. I'll try to reverse engineer it once it's working

Comment: ..like, I'm trying to link the chain too early in its scope?

Comment: I'm telling it to fork before it calls the router

Comment: @TurtleWolf With only your `<AddBarrel />` component as a reference, it's hard to tell exactly what your goal is when your `addBarrel()` method receives the response back from your server. All you're doing is pushing to `'/'` once axios resolves the promise.  If that's your goal, then this should work, but if you need to do something with the response, `console.log` the response above `this.props.history.push('/')`.